# How to see how many context switches a process makes in magenta kernel?

Tags: fuchsia, magenta-kernel

Is there any way to know how many context switches a process is doing in magenta kernel?

Note:

- Fuchsia's Magenta kernel is recently renamed to Zircon, however the below answer remains the same.
- Available `top` command gives following output:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this moment we cannot get the process / job / task specific details. Following details we cant get from `Fuchsia / Zircon (Magenta)`:

- `kstats -c` : To print system CPU status
- `kstats -m` : To print system Memory status

**CPU** stats columns will give following details:

- `cpu`: cpu #
- `load`: percentage load
- `sched`: scheduler stats --> Context switches, explicit thread yields, thread preemption events from interrupt
- `sysc` : syscalls
- `ints` : Interrupt stats (hardware, timer etc.)
- `ipi`: inter-process-interrupts